# Return null from Eloquent Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

so I got this code from Eloquent JS:

```
function findSolution(target) {
      function find(start, history) {
        if (start == target)
          return history;
        else if (start > target)
          return null;
        else
          return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
                 find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
      }
      return find(1, "1");
    }

    console.log(findSolution(24));
```

My problem is what *null* does in this recursion? When we get to the point where:

```
find(26, history) // start = 26, history = (1+5)+5)+5)+5)+5)
```

it hits `start > tagert` statement which is returning *null*.

So what happens next?

Comment: The caller gets a `null`. If it's the recursive call it'll be plugged into the `||` (logical or), or if it's the first one in `findSolution` then the entire result will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The `||` operator is a shortcut to return either the result of the first or the second call. If the first call to `find` returns null, then the result of the second is returned.

Null in this case means that the approach to reach the target was not successful. The function `findSolution` basically tries all combinations of `+ 5` and `* 3` to reach the target.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "or" (||) with a null value.

```
function findSolution(target) {
      function find(start, history) {
        if (start == target)
          return history;
        else if (start > target)
          return null;
        else
        {
            var result = find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)"); 
            if(result != null)
                return result;
            else
                return find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)"); 
        }

      }
      return find(1, "1");
    }

    console.log(findSolution(24));
```

Other solution:

```
function findSolution(target) {
      function find(start, history) {
        if (start == target)
          return history;
        else if (start > target)
          return false;
        else
          return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") || 
                 find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
      }
      return find(1, "1");
    }
```

The result is:

```
(((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a try:

The find function can only return 2 values regardless: either an string history or null. Once you reach any of the stopping conditions: `start == target` or `start > target`, that will be the result of the whole recursive call.

Now for each recursive call the code might create at most 2 more recursive calls. If the call to `find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)")` returns null (remember it can only return null or history) then `find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)")` will be executed as another attempt to return history, if that 2nd call also returns null then null will be your final result.

Comment: I would like to appreciate every answer here, but this one was very clear for me. Thanks.